# SQL delete in EXCEL VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I manage an Excel 2007 sheet using SQL, using the following connection string:

> Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='Invoice.xlsm';Extended
>   Properties='Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=Yes'

Everything works just as it should apart from the Delete statement.
When I try to perform `Delete From [tablename$] where code like '1')`, I get an error `-2147467259 (80004005)`.

I can't explain it, since all the other select and insert statements work just fine.

Comment: Ok. What ever I have tried, does not resolve the problem. I guess that perhaps Delete statements are not allowed for some reason. I am thinking of using a temporary sheet to write all data apart from the ones to be deleted and then ovewrite the original sheet with it.

Comment: What is the actual text of that error message? Does it offer any useful clues?

Comment: I am afraid not. It is a general sql error reporting that data cannot be deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching few hours in Microsoft Support, i found the following:

`The Catalog object has a Create method but does not have a Delete method.`

I guess there is no way to perform an SQL Delete statement, in excel sheets.

Comment: The ACE.OLEDB driver does not support Delete as you have found, but you can use another driver.